# How to get .NET Core SDK Version from registry?

Tags: .net-core, windows-10, registry

My operating system is **Windows 10 Professional**.

When I open **PowerShell** and run `dotnet --list-sdks` command, it list 3 .NET Core SDKs

> 1.0.0-preview2-003131 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
> 2.1.526 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
> 3.1.101 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

When I run `dotnet --version`, the output is

> 3.1.101

So the latest .NET Core SDK is **3.1.101**.

Then I open **Registry Editor** and go to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET Core\Shared Framework` key. It shows me 2 sub keys `v2.1` and `v3.1`.

When I go to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET Core\Shared Framework\v3.1` key, it shows me 2 sub keys: `3.1.1` and `3.1.18`. *I was expecting only 1 key* `3.1.1`. Why there are 2 keys?

When I go to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET Core\Shared Framework\v3.1\3.1.1` key, I can see that the `Version` attribute's Data is `3.1.1.0` which is correct.

When I go to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET Core\Shared Framework\v3.1\3.1.18` key, I can see that the `Version` attribute's Data is `3.1.18.21365`. Where is this coming from?

How to get correct .NET Core SDK Version from registry?